# SELECT Segment-IDs IF higher than average

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table named as combination_table. First I need to find **travel_time** `average`. And with this average I need to `select` **segmentids** which are **higher than the average** that we calculate.
Is it possible to write such a query?
[image]

Comment: What results do you want?  Each `segment_id` has multiple rows, so it is unclear what the desired results are.

Comment: As a query I need to find the segments if their **travel_time** higher than the average. Then in selection part I'm going to create a dictionary includes that segments and their **time** .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

calculate the average:

```
select avg(travel_time)
from combination_table;
```

Use this as a subquery:

```
select c1.segmentid
from combination_table c1
where c1.travel_time > (select avg(c2.travel_time)
                        from combination_table c2);
```

Comment: on this query, How can I ordered the **output** according to **time** column

Comment: `order by c1.travel_time`?

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . . I think you want aggregation and filtering:

```
select s.*
from (select segment_id, avg(travel_time) as avg_travel_time
      from combination_table ct
      group by segment_id
     ) s cross join
     (select avg(travel_time) as avg_travel_time
      from combination_table
     ) overall
where s.avg_travel_time > overall.avg_travel_time;
```

This returns `segment_id`s whose average travel time is bigger than the overall average.

Note:  This logic can also be implemented using window functions, but I think this formulation is clear in intent.